# VBA to copy all rows from one sheet and paste it to new sheet n times

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet which varies in terms of number of rows. But has 72 columns[A to BT].
Can some one please provide me VBA code  to copy the X number of rows to a new sheet in the same workbook n number of times?

Below is the code I have but,Here I am able to copy the 1200 rows but not able to paste it.

```
Sub test()
nrows = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Rows("1200").Copy
Sheet2.Rows("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I have even tried

Sheet2.Rows("1").Select

In both the cases I get error "424" Object required. Need help to resolve this issue,later I would like to put a loop to copy it to n sheet to n number of times, each time I would paste it to X*n+1 row, where X is number of rows and n is number of times the rows to be copied. Please assist me to copy for one iteration and if you would give me any pointers to loop I would appreciate the same.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting an entire row or rows for pasting, indicate only the top, left cell of the target range. (Note that if you try to do what you want to do as a user Excel will tell you the target Range has to match in size to the source Range. So as a user you'd click only the one cell before pasting. Same thing in VBA.)

Also, there's no need to actually *select* the target range in order to paste to it.

```
Sub test()
  nrows = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Sheet1.Rows("1200").Copy
  Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```